# Undeclared Identifier with Pointer to Component

Tags: delphi, pointers, undeclared-identifier

I have set up a pointer which I want to point to a component but the component it points to won't be the same one every time the procedure is called which it is simply declared as a 'Pointer'. Here is the code where the pointer is pointed to a component.

```
Procedure DestroyConnection(Component,ID,Connections:Integer);
Var
ComponentPtr: Pointer;

begin

if Component = 1 then
  ComponentPtr := Cell;

if Component = 2 then
   ComponentPtr := Bulb;
```

And here is the code where the pointer is reused.

```
Procedure DestroyLink(Ptr:Pointer; ID:Integer);
var
Component: ^TObject;
begin
Component := Ptr;
Component.Connected := False;
```

I get an undeclared identifier error on the line:

```
 Component.Connected := False;
```

How would I be able to access the component that the pointer points to in the procedure DestroyLink?
Sorry if I'm not making much sense :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `Component` is a pointer to `TObject`. And since `TObject` does not have a member named `Connected`, that is why the compiler objects.

What's more, you have one level of indirection too many. A variable of type `TObject`, or indeed any Delphi class is already a reference. It is already a pointer. Which is why your assignment to `ComponentPtr` does not use the `@` operator. It doesn't need to take the address since the reference already is an address.

You need to change `DestroyLink` to match. You need a variable that is not a pointer to a reference, but a variable of whatever the actual type of the object is. For example, suppose the type that defined the `Connected` property was `TMyComponent` then your code should be:

```
var
  Component: TMyComponent;
....
Component := TMyComponent(Ptr);
Component.Connected := False;
```

Or even simpler would be to change the type of the variable from `Pointer` to `TObject`. And then pass around `TObject` instead of `Pointer`. Then your code could read:

```
Procedure DestroyConnection(Component,ID,Connections:Integer);
Var
  Obj: TObject;
begin
  case Component of
  1:
    Obj := Cell;
  2:
    Obj := Bulb;
  ....
```

And then:

```
procedure DoSomethingWithObject(Obj: TObject);
begin
  if Obj is TCell then
    TCell(Obj).Connected := False;
  if Obj is TBulb then
    TBulb(Obj).SomeOtherProperty := SomeValue;
end;
```

If you had a common base class for all of these objects then you could declare your variable to be of that type. And you could then use virtual functions and polymorphism which I think would lead to much simpler and clearer code.